# Access LpVariable as input to another Keras sequential network

Tags: optimization, python

I want to use `LpVariable` as an input argument to a sequential CNN network layer, which is in Keras. When I tried to call the function I got the error as follows:

```
int(single_value)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'LpVariable'
```

Is there a way I can convert the `LpVariable` to integer values, so I can input it to my CNN network?

Answer (score 2):

You can use, `varValue` to get the values of your variable. Simply code as follow:

```
int(LpVariable[i].varValue)
```

here is an example from [this](http://benalexkeen.com/linear-programming-with-python-and-pulp-part-4/) link:

```
for var in ing_weight:
var_value = ing_weight[var].varValue
print "The weight of {0} in {1} sausages is {2} kg".format(var[1], var[0], var_value)
```

See also [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_8835/slides/chapter2.pdf) link.

Comment: Hi Oguz, I did use .varValue, how ever it only gives the final value of the Lpvariable after optimisation. What I need is the entire range of Lp variable as input to CNN, so I can optimise CNN architecture.

Comment: Hi @SruthySkaria, as you said varValue gives you the optimized value of the variable in the optimized model. If I am not wrong, what you need is all the values that each variable takes during the optimization process, which means values of variables in each iteration. If so, you need all the feasible solutions (with the variable values) throughout the process until the solver finds the optimal one. Is it a correct interpretation of what you need to have?

Comment: Yes Oguz, Basically I want to use the Linear programming to optimze my CNN netwrok, if that makes sense?